# Ошибка при установке kivy в PyCharm

Tags: python, kivy

Всем привет. Установил python 3.7.5 и PyCharm. В настройках Python Interpreter установил пакет Kivy. Но при запуске такого простейшего кода:

```
from kivy.app import App

class MyApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ExpenseTracker\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ExpenseTracker/main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\user\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-10-18_40.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ExpenseTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.5 (tags/v3.7.5:5c02a39a0b, Oct 15 2019, 00:11:34) [MSC v.1916 64 bit >(AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ExpenseTracker\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ExpenseTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ExpenseTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Как устранить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В PyCharm так и не удалось установить kivy. kivy получилось запустить в Sublime Text 3. Для этого я  вызвал консоль и последовательно вбил следующие команды. Тогда код с kivy запускается.
Ну и ещё такой момент, что на 20.10.2020 kivy ещё не работает на версиях питона выше 3.8. Поэтому я установил версию 3.7.5.

```
cd Desktop

py -m virtualenv kivy_venv

kivy_venv\Scripts\activate

python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1

python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.* kivy_deps.glew==0.1.*

python -m pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer==0.1.*

python kivy_venv\share\kivy-examples\demo\showcase\main.py
```